# Как игнорировать увеличение родителя при font-weight: bold?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Имею несколько `li`, у которых `display: inline-block` — это меню.

Дело в том, что активный пункты меню

- добавляет border в `2px` блоку `li`;
- делает шрифт внутри `li` жирным.

Так вот, когда текст делается жирным, то увеличивается ширина `li`, тогда все соседние справа блоки начинают прыгать (когда пункты меню активного меняются!).

Как от этого избавиться (не увеличивать ширину `li` при увеличении внутри его текста)?

**Обновление**

```
<ul class="type">
    <li class="active"><a href="">Все</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Обувь</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Аксесуары</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Детские магазины</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Подарки</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Прочее</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

```
li
    display inline-block
    padding 7px 12px;   
    margin-right 15px //add
    &.active
        border 2px solid #fdb913 //МАГАЗИНЫ
        border-radius 20px

        a
            border none
            font-weight bold
            color #b6b2a1   
    a
        font-size 18px
        display inline-block
        color textBlue
        border-bottom 1px solid #c1ddf1
```

Comment: покажите код меню

Comment: @soledar10, обновил вопрос

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556153/horiz-css-menu-text-shifting-on-bold-hover

Answer (score 4):

```css
ul {
  list-style-marker: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

li + li {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

a:before, a:after {
  content: attr(aria-label);
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

a:before {
  font-weight: bold;
  visibility: hidden;
}

a:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
}

a:hover:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="" aria-label="Все"></a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="" aria-label="Обувь"></a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="" aria-label="Аксесуары"></a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="" aria-label="Детские магазины"></a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="" aria-label="Подарки"></a>
  </li><li>
    <a href="" aria-label="Прочее"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно не увеличивать шрифт, а только сделать вид, что он увеличился.

```
li
  a
    transition: text-shadow 200ms
  &.active
    a
       text-shadow: 0 0 .45px #333, 0 0 .45px #333;
```

А можно задать li размер, и менять шрифт a внутри

```
li
  width: 60px // ставь сколько тебе нужно
  box-sizing: border-box
  &.active
    a
      font-weight: bold // если слово не становиться длиннее чем 60px, то никаких гличей не будет
```

Answer (score -1):

Есть вариант задать значение margin при active... только нужно знать величину, на которую шрифт сдвигает li... Что-то типа:

```
li:active {
  margin: 0 -2px;
}
```

Дальше подбирайте `margin` — и вауля.

Comment: Брррррррррррррррр

Answer (score -1):

```
li:active 
{
  margin: 0 -2px;
}
```

Comment: Разве это решает поставленную задачу?

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

Можно выводить при наведении скрытый тег с нужным оформлением с position:absolute, а старое оформление прятать (например visibility:hidden). Правда для этого придется изменить html файл

```
<ul class="type">
  <li class="active">
    <a href=""><span class="normal">Все</span><span class="bold">Все</span></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href=""><span class="normal">Обувь</span><span class="bold">Обувь</span></a>
  </li>
...
</ul>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
a:hover { text-shadow: 1px,0,0,color; }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развернутые ответы.